# Missing required parameters for [Route: Admin.update] [URI: Admin/{Admin}]

Tags: laravel

I get the fallowing error. `Missing required parameters for [Route: Admin.update] [URI: Admin/{Admin}].` It only disappear if i comment the form of the edit.blade. I checked what i did wrong but couldn't find it.

I also checked my web.php but i doub't it is comming from there.

If someone can see the error i would be happy.

Here is my route,

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::resource('Admin', AdminController::class);
```

this is me admin controller

```
<?php

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
     */
    public function edit(User $user)
    {

        $roles = Role::all();

        return view('Admin.edit', [ 'user' => $user, 'roles' => $roles]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
//        $user->roles()->sync($request->roles);
//
//        return redirect()->route('Admin.index');
    }
}
```

This is me edit blade.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="admin-first-page">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>User edit page</h2>
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam amet aperiam blanditiis consequatur dolore id iste itaque nisi officia reiciendis! Distinctio dolor dolore doloremque esse impedit, iusto nostrum quidem vitae?</p>

            <form action="{{ route('Admin.update', $user) }}" method="post">
                    @method('PUT')
                    @csrf


                    @foreach($roles as $role)
                        <input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="{{$role->id}}">
                        <label>{{ $role->name }}</label>
                    @endforeach

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Update
                </button>
           </form>

        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Comment: can you provide the route definition for this route?

Comment: @lagbox I updated the post.

Comment: The key to the answer below is knowing that `Route::resource('Admin', AdminController::class);` creates a route like `Route::get('/admins/{admin}/edit', [AdminController::class, 'edit'])->name('admins.edit');` and noting the name of the place holder is "admin" not "user"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to match the typehinted parameter of your Controller method to the route parameter name, in this case it would be `Admin`. So your `edit` method needs to be:

```
public function edit(User $Admin)
{
    return view('Admin.edit', ['user' => $Admin, ...]);
}
```

At the moment you are getting a non existing instance of the `User` model as Dependency Injection instead of Route Model Binding because `Admin` does not match  `$user`. So you are passing a `null` value to the `route` helper:

```
route(..., $user);
```

Since `$user` is a non existing Model instance its "id" is `null` and you can't pass `null`s to the route helper.